# Comparing array from document properties to dataRange not working

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, google-apps-script, google-sheets

So I have a script (google apps script) that pulls data from one of my sheets (to pairs: initials && percentage) that has changing values (sometimes it's only weekly other times it's daily).

It's supposed to check the old values against the new values and only process the new values, but it's processing for all values for some reason.

During the loop process it starts by finding the email attached to that cell and then sends a generated email to the person. Then at the end it stores the new values found over the previous.

Getting New Data & Variables

```
var data = dataRange.getValues(); // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
    var oldData = [{}];
    //Declare variable
```

Getting Old Data from document properties.

```
var oldValues = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties().getProperties();
//get values from document properties 
var outerArrayOldData = [];
//empty array
var arr4 = [];
//empty array
var thisLoopString,
    thisRowArray;
for (var key in oldValues) {
    //grabbing keys from document properties 'row[i]' and loop for each
    thisLoopString = oldValues[key];
    thisRowArray = []; //Reset
    array
    thisRowArray = thisLoopString.split(","); //Convert the string to partial array
    arr4.push(thisRowArray); //Push the inner array into the outer array

    outerArrayOldData = arr4.concat(outerArrayOldData); //convert outer to actual usable array
    var arr4 = []; //reset arr4 back to 0
};

//End getting old data
```

Comparing old data to new data

```
    var oldData = outerArrayOldData;
    var source = oldData.map(function (row) {
            return JSON.stringify(row);
            //map array to string
        }),
        searchRow,
        dataLength = data.length;
    for (i = 0; i < dataLength; i += 1) {
        searchRow = JSON.stringify(data[i]);
        if (source.indexOf(searchRow) == -1) {
            //search old data and compare to new data using index search and if data isn't in old stack process it through functions

                //doing stuff with new pairs
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How old data is stored to Doc properties.

```
    var objOldData = {};
    //empty
    var keyName = "",
        //empty
        thisRowArray;
    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        keyName = "row" + (i).toString();
        //set keys
        thisRowArray = data[i].toString();
        //convert each pair array to string
        if (thisRowArray == "") continue;
        //skip blanks

        objOldData[keyName] = thisRowArray;
        //add keys and values to properties as a string
    }
    PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties().setProperties(objOldData,
        true); //true deletes all other properties
    //Store the Updated/New Values back to Properties

}
```

Logger Console:

```
<<<<<<<<Imported Range data>>>>>>>>
[[BBB, 0.9], [CCC, 0.76], [DDD, 0.89], [, ]]

<<<<<<<<Old data from dpcument properties>>>>>>>>
[[DDD, 0.89], [, ], [BBB, 0.9], [CCC, 0.76]]


<<<<<Processing New Values Not in Old Data>>>>>
[CCC, 0.76]
[BBB, 0.9]
[DDD, 0.89]

 <<<<<<<<Store the Updated/New Values back to Properties>>>>>>>>
 {row1=CCC,0.76, row0=BBB,0.9, row3=,, row2=DDD,0.89}
```

As you can see it's still processing all the values even though they are not new and already exist in the system. How come the search isn't finding that they already exist? WHere did I go wrong on this?

Comment: It might help if you reduce your issue to the minimum required to demonstrate it. Posting over 100 lines of uncommented code makes life difficult for those who might like to answer.

Comment: @RobG I removed what I knew for sure wasn't causing an issue and added more comments...

Comment: Regarding "the minimun required to demostrate it", see [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for further details. Don't forget to include a sample of the "old data".

Comment: @Ruben that is why I includes the logger console output.

Comment: The logger console output looks to me to be too cluttered, so I didn't pay attention to it. I'm sorry.

Comment: @Runén sorry about that. Didn't clean it up like I should have.

Comment: @hakarune I don't understand your map syntax. You're calling a closure as the callback. But you're also then also passing *searchRow* and *dataLength* to the var *source*. What is it you're trying to do? In effect, it reads like this: `var source = oldData.map(function (row) { ... }),         searchRow,  dataLength = data.length;`

Comment: @Sujay searchRow and dataLength don't get passed to source. `source` is just the old data as a string to be searched.

Comment: Here is the output from logger @Sujay: `source:  [["DDD","0.89"], ["",""], ["BBB","0.9"], ["CCC","0.76"]]` && `searchRow: undefined` && `DataLength: 4.0`

Comment: @hakarune well your map syntax still doesn't make sense. Please go thru what I wrote. Why exactly do you have *searchRow* in that line if its old data to be searched? I am just not able to make sense of it.

Comment: It's just declaring an empty variable.

Comment: ok. then please write that in separate lines, since it wasn't readable. reg. the actual problem I don't know. You need to post a minimal complete code which has the console output statements included so someone else can run it and check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your "Comparing old data to new data" for loop code, try changing:

```
searchRow = JSON.stringify(data[i]);
```

to:

```
searchRow = JSON.stringify([data[i][0], data[i][1].toString()]);
```

This ensures that the value at the second array index is always converted into a string for comparison to the "old" imported value, which appears to be parsed from a row delivered as a string.

It looks like, currently, new data array values declared with the second value as numeric, (or perhaps null or empty value):

```
 [["BBB", 0.9], ["CCC", 0.76], ["DDD", 0.89], ["",""]];
```

While "old" rows (imported from Google doc) are imported and converted into an array, where the values are strings:

```
 [["CCC","0.76"],["BBB","0.9"],["",""],["DDD","0.89"]]
```

On comparing rows with JSON.stringify, for example, '["DDD","0.89"]' does not match '["DDD",0.89]', so all rows are getting erroneously registered as "new".

I did a bit of guessing from your example to arrive at this, but it could be the cause of your bug. Good luck!

Comment: Boom! Thank you!! I didn't even see that discrepancy. The minor change fixed it perfectly. Now it works 100% 10/10 runs perfect.

Answer (score 1):

I have trouble understanding your code, so I created my own instead:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
var data = {};

function getData() {

  var range = sheet.getRange("A1:B3");
  var values = range.getValues();

  for (var i=0; i < values.length; i++) {

    var key = 'row' + i;
    var currentRow = values[i];

    // for each cell value,
    //   toString : convert to string
    //   trim     : remove all whitespaces from both ends of cell values
    //   encode…  : encode the values so we don't have any ","
    var arr = currentRow.map(function(v){return encodeURIComponent(v.toString().trim())});

    // join the array with "," delimiter
    var s = arr.join();

    data[key] = s;
  }  
} // getData()

function saveData() {
  getData();
  PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties().setProperties(data);
}

function compareData() {
  getData();
  var props = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties().getProperties();
  for (var idx in props) {
    if (idx in data) {
      if (data[idx] != props[idx]) {
        Logger.log('\n%s is different\nOld value is "%s"\nNew value is "%s"',
                   idx,
                   decodeURIComponent(props[idx]),
                   decodeURIComponent(data[idx]));
      }
    } else {
      Logger.log('missing row: ' + idx);
    }
  }  
}

// Test function. Check all document properties
function peekProperties() {
 var props = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties().getProperties();
 for (var idx in props) {
   Logger.log('%s = %s', idx, props[idx]);
 }
}
```

Question: what if a row is deleted? Shouldn't `key` be the value in A column instead of row number?